# FFT output from SciPy is confusing or may be I misunderstood

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, fft

I am applying FFT from SciPy package on a 1D signal. This signal has been captured at 512hz sampling rate which means 512 data points in 1s. I have 5 min of data overall.

When I apply FFT from SciPy on this signal using the code below I get the FFT applied on entire signal at once. In my understanding when I apply FFT on the signal with the sampling rate at 512, the FFT gets applied to first 512 points then next 512 data points and so on but here FFT gets applied to an entire signal at once which I don't understand.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import zscore
from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq,rfft, rfftfreq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df =  pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=True)
print(df.head())

# measuring the fft of the signal
def plotFFT(df):#,cleanDF):
    sampleRate = 512 # Hz
    duration = df.shape[0]
    
    xf = rfftfreq(duration,1/sampleRate)
    yf = rfft(df['value'])
    
    fig = plt.figure(num='FFT of signal', figsize=(20,10))
    plt.plot(xf,np.real(yf),label='raw')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress(0)
    plt.close(fig)

plotFFT(df)
```

When I change the line

```
yf = rfft(df['value'])
```

to

```
yf = rfft(df['value'],n=sampleRate)
```

I get this error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/BLACK/Desktop/PythonXperiments/FFTScipy/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BLACK/Desktop/PythonXperiments/FFTScipy/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    plotFFT(df)
  File "C:/Users/BLACK/Desktop/PythonXperiments/FFTScipy/main.py", line 21, in plotFFT
    plt.plot(xf, np.real(yf), label='raw')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2840, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 399, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (53378,) and (257,)
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more please? I don't understand  the SciPy package . I tried to read the documentation but example are really simple and doesn't explain in depth.

Comment: @JohnHennig I tried your suggestions

Comment: [Wikipedia for FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform): "A fast Fourier transform (FFT) is an algorithm that computes the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of a sequence [...]". So please read the [Wikipedia page for DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) so you know what you are doing. There is no sampling rate involved in the DFT at all, it's just about a sequence of numbers.

Comment: Your error is because you set the `n` parameter in the call to the `fft`, which changes the output length. When you now call `plot`, the two arrays don't have the same length.

Comment: @CrisLuengo so should I apply FFT on 512 sample  window or on the entire signal?

Comment: I don't know what you should do because I don't know what you want to accomplish. You can apply the FFT to the whole signal, or to smaller windows, overlapping or non-overlapping, depending on your application. There is no need for windows to be 1s long, the window length should be adjusted depending on your particular application.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a year and I don't know if you already got a solution, but I'm hoping I can shed some light on the subject:

This program uses scipy, a hanning window, and writes the results on an excel sheet, so I am hoping that this example could help people to understand what is happening from going from time to frequency.

1.- You need to run this program as admin
2.- After the excel file has been created, check it out, and if you change the values, and re-run the program, you need to either close the excel file, or save it as another file.
3.- Works in pyhton 3 and windows 10-11

```
# using openpyxl and scipy... install numpy as well if you don't already have it.
# It's also, VERY, important to run python as administrator (cause openpyxl will write data to your computer, and windows requires python to be running as admin)
# Also, VERY important, close the excel file before attempting to create another one, or save it as something else, other wise you'll get errors

from scipy.fft import rfft
from scipy.signal import hann
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import  load_workbook, Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, colors, PatternFill
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series

sample_rate = 2048                                          # sample rate are values 2^n; 1024, 2048, 4096, etc
N = 2048                                                    # Number of samples taken (multiple of 2.56 - thinking about vibration analysis)
f_max = int(sample_rate/2.56)
lines = N/2.56                                     
wait_time = N/sample_rate                                   # again, in vibration analysis, this is known as the Data Adquisition Time (1s for this example)
jump_c = f_max/lines                                        # This is going to be the delta frequency (maximum frequency divided by samples)
 
t = np.linspace(0, wait_time, N)
y = (10)*np.sin(2*np.pi*60*t) + (5)*np.sin(2*np.pi*120*t)  # sin function with two components: 60 Hz and 120 Hz you can play with the frequencies as well as amplitudes

win_1 = hann(N)                                             # Hanning window will be used, windows are an entirely different subject, check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function
w_1 = rfft(y*win_1)                                         # this is the real fft of the y function (it will create an array of 2048/2.56) without its negative part
w_1 = np.abs(w_1).astype(int)                               # only caring about the positive values

filename = 'test.xlsx'                                      # this file is going to be over written, you need to run python as admin (if on windows)

wb = Workbook()                                             # Openpyxl config to open and create the first sheet
ws1 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet_A', 0)                         
ws1.title = 'osc to specter'

ws1['A1'].font = Font(bold = True)
ws1.cell(row = 10, column = 1).value = 'time'
ws1.cell(row = 10, column = 2).value = 'original funct'
ws1.cell(row = 10, column = 3).value = 'frec'
ws1.cell(row = 10, column = 4).value = 'frec amplitude'

row_j = 11

for k in range(len(t)):
    ws1.cell(row = row_j, column = 1).value = t[k]*1000     # This to get it on ms
    ws1.cell(row = row_j, column = 2).value = y[k]
    row_j = row_j + 1

chart_1 = ScatterChart()
chart_1.y_axis.title = 'Amplitude'
chart_1.x_axis.title = 'ms'

tvalues = Reference(ws1, min_col = 1, min_row = 11, max_row = row_j)  

yvalues_1 = Reference(ws1, min_col = 2, min_row = 11, max_row = row_j)
series_1 = Series(yvalues_1, tvalues, title = 'Oscillogram')
series_1.graphicalProperties.line.width = 9500
chart_1.x_axis.tickLblPos = 'low'
chart_1.height = 10
chart_1.width = 30
chart_1.x_axis.scaling.max = wait_time*1000                 # Also, to get it on ms
chart_1.x_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart_1.legend = None
chart_1.series.append(series_1)
ws1.add_chart(chart_1, 'F1')

row_i = 11

frec = np.arange(0, f_max, jump_c)

for j in range(len(frec)):
    
    ws1.cell(row = row_i, column = 3).value = frec[j]
    ws1.cell(row = row_i, column = 4).value = w_1[j]/(len(w_1)/2)     # it needs to be divided, otherwise amplitude is really high
    
    row_i = row_i + 1

xvalues = Reference(ws1, min_col = 3, min_row = 11, max_row = row_i)

chart_2 = ScatterChart()
chart_2.y_axis.title = 'Amplitude'
chart_2.x_axis.title = 'Hz'

yvalues_2 = Reference(ws1, min_col = 4, min_row = 11, max_row = row_i)
series_2 = Series(yvalues_2, xvalues, title = 'Hanning window')
series_2.graphicalProperties.line.width = 9500 # This is in EMUs, apparently openpyxly transforms this divided by something to obtain pixels; 9500 will give 7.5 px
chart_2.x_axis.tickLblPos = 'low'
chart_2.height = 10
chart_2.width = 30
chart_2.x_axis.scaling.max = f_max
chart_2.x_axis.scaling.min = 0
chart_2.legend = None                        # Otherwise, you could select with legend.position = 'b' (r = right, l = left, t = top, b = bottom, tr = top right. Default is r)
chart_2.series.append(series_2)
ws1.add_chart(chart_2, 'F21')

wb.save(filename)                                                   # Saving 'da' file
print ('saved file')
```